# Create React App: ESLint config is not working with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have created a react app using CRA **(typescript template)** and TypeScript is not following rules written in ESLint config. This is quite weird for me because I use this config in every react project I setup. I'm sharing below some information that might be useful.

#### .eslintrc

None of the rules written below are being followed by TypeScript.

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["react-hooks"],
  "extends": ["airbnb-typescript", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": { "project": "./tsconfig.json" },
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "newline-before-return": "error",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error",
    "lines-between-class-members": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 1 }],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "always-multiline",
        "objects": "always-multiline",
        "imports": "always-multiline",
        "exports": "always-multiline",
        "functions": "always-multiline"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "config",
    "public",
    "scripts",
    "serviceWorker.ts",
    "setupTests,ts"
  ]
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.62",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.8",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  }
}
```

**Note:** React app has been ejected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Fixed:

My editor VS Code was missing this in `settings.json`: **"eslint.validate": ["typescript", "typescriptreact"]**

This is needed to explicitly tell ESLint to watch TypeScript files for linting errors (by default it lints only JavaScript and JSX files).

Hope this helps you as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

These things usually happens when I'm using VSCODE. Usually there are 3 things I do to Fix. If this config works for you in other projects it might be usefull.

1. Run the "Reload Window" in VSCODE, usually fix the problem for me
2. Delete the node_modules and reinstall de deps, I use yarn and it fixed the problem before
3. It might worth reacreate manually the .eslintrc . Maybe there's an update in CRA and things changed. Usually I start a new project and run eslint --init and start creating a new eslintrc

And it's cool to check if the eslint plugin is workin in your IDE.

*obs : I woul'd post this as a comment, however I can't yet.*

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your suggestions. I have already tried first two points but I would like to have more information from you on how CRA has updated and things have changed :)

Comment: Yes of course. The thing happened once for me. I usually setup my ESLINT manually every project. And the last step it asks and installs the deps needed for ESLINT. The thing is it was installing an older version of ESLINT, so from now on I install the deps myself. Not sure if it could be related to react updated or not, but as soon as I did that it worked like a charm. But I'm glad you solved your problem